# Why does the function file in the host comes back to the first mood?

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system

I changed the theme and it doesn't work well,it gives the following error:

```
public_html/wp-content/themes/7/dt-the7/inc/shortcodes/includes/gap/function.php line 56
```

I found the problem and removed the `function _check_active_widget()`,but this error appeared for all of the folders so I changed `function.php` file. It worked well for sometime. But after an hour when I changed the settings of site in WordPress, all of the function files re-changed to the first mood,and they had `function _check_active_widget()` again. I remove them again and again but it keeps coming back.

**My Question is:**

Why doesn't it work well?

Why is the mood getting reset?

And finally, how can I fix these function files?

Comment: please show your whole error.

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot redeclare _check_active_widget() (previously declared in /home/fxijdcel/public_html/wp-content/themes/7/dt-the7/functions.php:2142) in /home/fxijdcel/public_html/wp-content/themes/7/dt-the7/inc/shortcodes/includes/columns/functions.php on line 86

Comment: this error because you want to redeclare that function. There are also a function called `redeclare _check_active_widget()`.

Comment: i dont change the function.php file ;it redeclare itself;
where is **redeclare _check_active_widget()** ?

Comment: try to search in all of your source files strin `function _check_active_widget`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to surround the function in

```
 /home/fxijdcel/public_html/wp-content/themes/7/dt-the7/inc/shortcodes/includes/c‌​olumns/functions.php on line 86
```

with

```
if( !function_exists ( '_check_active_widget' ) )
```

In this way you declare this function only if is not been yet declared